# Issues with join statement not displaying records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, join

I'm trying to accomplish the following:  Display all rows for Mgt.Dbo.Tab1 (157 rows)  while joining 3 tables.  The query only provides results for 76 rows from Mgt.  i've tried using left join to no avail.  HELP! TIA

Code:

```
select 
    mgt.UID
  , Mgt.emp_num
  , emp.EMP_NAME
  , RTRIM(mgt.COMPANY)
  , 'Company 1'
  , jnl.d_w
  , mgt.d_r
  , jnl.UNITS
  , jnl.RATE
  , mgt.hours
  , mgt.RATE
  , rtrim(jnl.MEMO)
  , mgt.UNIQUE_ID
  , jnl.grow
  , jnl.grow_num
  , hdr.ch_date
  , mgt.sub_by
  , hdr.ch_num
from Mgt.dbo.sick as mgt
  inner join Comp1.DBO.emp as emp
    on Mgt.emp_num = emp.emp_num
  inner join Comp1.dbo.hdr as hdr
    on Mgt.emp_num = hdr.emp_num
  inner join Comp1.dbo.jnl as jnl
    on jnl.c_n = hdr.c_n
where COMPANY in ('Test') 
  and jnl.wg = 'SP' 
  and mgt.d_r = jnl.d_w 
  and mgt.d_r >= '8/20/2017' 
  and mgt.d_r <= '9/1/2017'
  and mgt.d_r=jnl.d_w
```

Comment: I'd like to buy some aliases please.

Comment: @SqlZim ;-) the names have been changed to protect the innocent

Comment: no, not like Dragnet. Like table aliases and prefixing columns with the source table. [How to alias your tables - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). Each column should be prefixed with the table alias for the table it is sourced from, that way we can tell you how to fix your query with left joins and by moving criteria from your `where` to your join conditions.

Comment: oh ok.  I've been reading up on it.  It's new to me so my apologies.  I'm sure it'd help readability

Comment: Change all those joins to left joins. If that doesn't do it, focus on the where clause. The point is, your inner joins and where clauses is what will be limiting your result set in this query.

Answer (score 0):

After your edit, swap your `inner join`s for `left join`s and move any `where` clauses on left joined tables to the join condition:

```
select 
    mgt.UID
  , mgt.emp_num
  , emp.EMP_NAME
  , RTRIM(mgt.COMPANY)
  , 'Company 1'
  , jnl.d_w
  , mgt.d_r
  , jnl.UNITS
  , jnl.RATE
  , mgt.hours
  , mgt.RATE
  , rtrim(jnl.MEMO)
  , mgt.UNIQUE_ID
  , jnl.grow
  , jnl.grow_num
  , hdr.ch_date
  , mgt.sub_by
  , hdr.ch_num
from Mgt.dbo.sick as mgt
  left join Comp1.DBO.emp as emp
    on Mgt.emp_num = emp.emp_num
  left join Comp1.dbo.hdr as hdr
    on Mgt.emp_num = hdr.emp_num
  left join Comp1.dbo.jnl as jnl
    on jnl.c_n = hdr.c_n
   and jnl.wg = 'SP' 
   and jnl.d_w = mgt.d_r
where mgt.COMPANY in ('Test') 
  and mgt.d_r >= '8/20/2017' 
  and mgt.d_r <= '9/1/2017'
```

Comment: as a result of making the switch, i now show 14108 records.  shouldn't by adding left join, the maximum amount of records that could be displayed would be max rows in mgt?

Comment: @BIGTONE559 I would say you are missing some join criteria, as each row from `mgt` is matching multiple rows in a join. perhaps `jnl` has another column to join on, like `emp_num` ?

Comment: the problem is definitely with my join statement.  doing a bit more homework i'll let you know what i find.

Comment: @BIGTONE559 Good luck!

Comment: first problem that i've identified is that the line mgt.d_r=jnl.d_w             when included in the join statement it results in multiple records from the jnl table (multiple records that have the same dates as mgt.d_r).  The problem is when included in the where clause it will not display rows from mgt.d_r where there is no record on the same day in jnl.d_w ;-(!

Answer (score 0):

it appears the following did the trick:

```
select 
mgt.UID
, mgt.emp_num
, emp.EMP_NAME
, RTRIM(mgt.COMPANY)
, 'Company 1'
, jnl.d_w
, mgt.d_r
, jnl.UNITS
, jnl.RATE
, mgt.hours
, mgt.RATE
, rtrim(jnl.MEMO)
, mgt.UNIQUE_ID
, jnl.grow
, jnl.grow_num
, hdr.ch_date
, mgt.sub_by
, hdr.ch_num
from Mgt.dbo.sick as mgt
left join Comp1.DBO.jnl as jnl
        inner join comp1.dbo.hdr as hdr 
        on jnl.c_n= hdr.c_n
on jnl.d_w=mgt.d_r
and mgt.unique_id=jnl.memo
and hdr.emp_num=mgt.emp_num
where mgt.COMPANY in ('Test') 
and mgt.d_r >= '8/20/2017' 
and mgt.d_r <= '9/1/2017'
```

I was missing an inner join.